# java - create a text file with all possible combinations of 0 and 1 (size n)

Tags: java, algorithm, file, combinations

I created a text file via java. And the file should contain all the possible combinations of 0 and 1 at length n.

for example, the combinations of n=3 are:

000,001,010,011,100,101,110,111

and the file should contain:

000001010011110

and not:

000001010011100101110111

Because the algorithm checks if each combinations is already in the file.

I have developed the algorithm which does that, but it's very slow because of the method that check if combinations already exist in the file (inFile()).

And I cant use String which may contain the combinations, because if I will try to generate for length 20, the length of the string will be 2^20*20, and it's takes time to eclipse to analyze that.

The algorithm:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Test
{
    public static String FileName = "file.txt";
    public static int size = 20;
    public static FileReader fr;
    public static BufferedReader br;
    public static FileWriter fw;
    public static BufferedWriter bw;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try
        {
            fw = new FileWriter(FileName, true);
            bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

            try
            {
                fr = new FileReader(FileName);
                br = new BufferedReader(fr);
                doit(size);
                System.out.println("\n>> finished");
                br.close();
            }
            catch(FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                System.out.println("File was not found!");
            }
            catch(IOException e)    
            {
                System.out.println("No file found!");
            }

            bw.close();
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error1!");
        }
        catch(IOException e)    
        {
            System.out.println("Error2!");
        }
    }

    public static void doit(int l) {
        String s="",c="";
        for(int i=0;i<l;s+="0",c+="1",i++);
        write(s);
        while(!s.equals(c)) {
            for(int z=l-1;z>=0;z--) {
                if(s.charAt(z) == '1')
                    continue;
                s = s.substring(0,z);
                s += "1";
                for(int b=0;b<l-z-1;b++) {
                    s+="0";
                }
                z=-1;
            }
            if(!inFile(s)) {
                write(s);
            }
        }
    }

    public static boolean inFile(String sub) {
        try
        {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FileName));
            String line = br.readLine();
            if(line.indexOf(sub) != -1)
                return true;
            return false;
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: file to read from not found");
            return false;
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error: file to read from not found - 2");
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static void write(String s) {
        try
        {
            bw.write(s);
            bw.flush();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Error3!");
        }
    }
}
```

When the length is longer (more than 20) it's getting worse.
**What should I do to make it faster?**

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [generate all n bit binary numbers in a fastest way possible](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12325868/generate-all-n-bit-binary-numbers-in-a-fastest-way-possible)

Comment: First of all, construct the string in memory, perform checks on that one, and only involve file IO once you're done with that. Past that, I think this is going in the direction of asymptotic complexity...

Comment: This is not double check, maybe you didn't understand.
it does this check because after the third writing there is a possibility that the combination is already exist between other combinations.
001 and 101 contain also 110

Comment: Siguza, if i create a string and insert to the string the combinations and the length is long (more than 15) the size of the string is going to be 2^15*15, it's a lot. and to analyze that it's going to take a lot of time

Comment: @freedev But when you create `001` and `100`, how do you derive from that that `010` exists already?

Comment: because in the file it like: 001100 and there is also in this string 110 and 011

Comment: @ShaiLA Would you also be okay with a more dense solution? E.g., the string `000100110111` is shorter than your solution, but still contains all permutations for n=3...

Comment: I accept every solution that will create a file with all the possible combinations. You can post a code that does it better if you like to help me.

Comment: @ShaiLa I think I found.

Comment: What you're looking for are De Bruijn sequences: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence 
In this answer I explain the FKM algorithm to generate De Bruijn sequences: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35370539/longest-binary-sequence-with-no-equal-n-length-subsequences/35389332#35389332

Comment: Have you found a solution using any of the methods to generate De Bruijn sequences?

Comment: @m69 no... because when the length is 25, it's slow. I want to insert the final string into these text file, so with this way, it's almost impossible.

Comment: @m69 it's slow because the length of the string will be very long, and storing a long string makes each line of code slower.

Comment: What's the maximum number of bits you want to generate the sequence for,  and what kind of speed were you hoping to achieve?

Comment: @m69 I want to generate the combinations for length = 25 and more, if it's possible I wish for length 100.  1 - 2 hours maximum

Comment: The sequence for length 100 is more than 2^100 digits long; stored as a text file, that's 1,152,921,504,606,846,976 terabytes of data. For length 50 you get 1024 TB of data. Somewhere around 40 will be the maximum practical length.

Comment: @m69 30 will be enough. But, do you have an idea how to create the file of length 30 fast? I can't run a code for days.

Comment: I translated the ideas from my 2 answers to the linked question into C code and I get length 25 in 39 seconds, 26 in 84s, 27 in 227s... You could probably speed it up further with parallel processing.

Comment: @m69 what do you mean by parallel processing? How can I do parallel processing with De Bruijn sequences? Because the algorithm is based on the existence string which generated, and being changed during the processing.

Comment: (I got 22m30s for the 1GB file for length 30, using 1 core of an i5) Please have a look at the question and answers I linked to. The FKM and similar algorithms do not require that you check the whole sequence to know whether a number is already present in the sequence.

Comment: Btw, if the length is a prime number, the "aperiodic prefix" part of the FKM algorithm can be skipped, because only 0000... and 1111... are reduced to 0 and 1. So length 29 or 31 will be much faster than 30.

Comment: @m69 I tried your code, and when the length is 30, I got an error that the string length is invalid at the console. I use the JS code on Chrome browser. When I tried on Internet Explorer I got an error: Out of memory at line: 1

Comment: Of course, no browser is expecting a script to insert 1GB of text into a page.

Answer (score 1):

When generating all bit-strings of length n, there will be n^2 possibilities. To generate all of these possibilities algorithmically, you can generate the bit-string for each integer less than n^2.

As in your example of n = 3, 3^2 is 8 so we need to use all integers less than 8:
The bit-string of length three for 0 is 000.
The bit-string of length three for 1 is 001.
The bit-string of length three for 2 is 010.
The bit-string of length three for 3 is 011.
The bit-string of length three for 4 is 100.
The bit-string of length three for 5 is 101.
The bit-string of length three for 6 is 110.
The bit-string of length three for 7 is 111.

We can generate these using the following java method:

```
Integer.toBitString(4)
```

will return "100". However, there is a problem, this will not pad the number with zeros so that it reaches an appropriate length.

```
Integer.toBitString(1)
```

will return "1". To solve this, we can use a java method to pad the integer with an appropriate number of spaces, and then replace the spaces with 0's as follow:

```
String.format("%3s", Integer.toBinaryString(1)).replace(' ', '0')
```

Using a for loop, you can generate and print these Strings to a file

```
for(int i = 0; i < math.Pow(n, 2); i++) {
    String poss = String.format("%*s", n, Integer.toBinaryString(i)).replace(' ', '0')
    filePrintStream.print(poss);
}
```

This will generate every possible bit-string in order without duplicates.

Comment: I expect that actual code would save `Math.pow(n, 2)` somewhere and don't recompute it for each loop iteration.

Comment: I think java will optimize that, not evaluate it each iteration, but it should be `Math.pow(2, n)` not the other way round.

Answer (score 0):

the file should contain: 000001010011110 or 0001010011110 ? (same thing could go for the ..1111...)

If you know what to print then you dont have to check:

```
 public static void main(String []args){
    int n = 4;

    print(n,0);
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        print(i,1);
        print(i,0);
    }
    print(n,1);
    System.out.println("");

 }
    static void print(int max, int number){
        for (int j=0;j<max;j++){
            System.out.print(number);
        }
    }
```

Comment: the file should contain all the possible combinations, in any order. I just want to avoid from repeated, in order to save memory.

Comment: Could you please check if the following answer for 
n=3 : 000101100111

n=4 : 00001011001110001111

n=5 : 000001011001110001111000011111

Comment: The problem is not the memory is avoid to generate the combination that you don't need...