# Get an 2 dimension array with 0 and 1 combination

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

My English is not good,  so please forgive me if what I describle is not clear for you.

I want to create 2 dimension Array with `0` and `1`
when I input `n`, it should create: `Array01(1 to 2^n as long, n as long)`, and `0` and `1` is combination like this:

```
n = 1 ==> Arr (2 rows x 1 column)
0 |
1 |
```

```
n = 2 ==> Arr (4 rows x 2 columns)
0 0 |
0 1 |
1 0 |
1 1 |
```

```
n = 3 ==> Array (8 rows x 3 columns)
0 0 0 |
0 0 1 |
0 1 0 |
1 0 0 |
1 1 0 |
1 0 1 |
0 1 1 |
1 1 1 |
```

Comment: Are you looking for : https://stackoverflow.com/a/12329045/7602468 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a function like below

```
Option Explicit

Public Function CreateMatrix(ByVal n As Long) As Variant
    Dim Matrix() As Long
    ReDim Matrix(1 To 2 ^ n, 1 To n)
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To 2 ^ n - 1
        Dim BinaryString As String
        BinaryString = DecToBin(i, n)
        
        Dim c As Long
        For c = 1 To n
            Matrix(i + 1, c) = CLng(Mid$(BinaryString, c, 1))
        Next c
    Next i
    
    CreateMatrix = Matrix
End Function


Public Function DecToBin(ByVal DecimalIn As Variant, Optional ByVal NumberOfBits As Variant) As String
    Dim Result As String
    
    DecimalIn = CDec(DecimalIn)
    
    Do While DecimalIn <> 0
        Result = Trim$(Str$(DecimalIn - 2 * Int(DecimalIn / 2))) & Result
        DecimalIn = Int(DecimalIn / 2)
    Loop
    
    If Not IsMissing(NumberOfBits) Then
        If Len(Result) > NumberOfBits Then
            Result = "Error - Number too large for bit size"
        Else
            Result = Right$(String$(NumberOfBits, "0") & Result, NumberOfBits)
        End If
    End If
    
    DecToBin = Result
End Function
```

and call it like

```
' generate the matrix
Dim MyMatrix() As Long
MyMatrix = CreateMatrix(n:=3)

' and write it to a sheet
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1").Resize(UBound(MyMatrix, 1), UBound(MyMatrix, 2)).Value = MyMatrix
```

---

#### How does this work?

If we look at the matrix below we can see each row as a binary number that can be converted into a decimal number. So binary `000` is decimal `0`, then binary `001` is decimal `1` and binary `010` is decimal `2` and so on:

```
0 0 0 |  'decimal 0
0 0 1 |  'decimal 1
0 1 0 |  'decimal 2
1 0 0 |  'decimal 3
1 1 0 |  'decimal 4
1 0 1 |  'decimal 5
0 1 1 |  'decimal 6
1 1 1 |  'decimal 7
```

So we know if we want to create that matrix we need to convert the decimal numbers `1` to `7` into binary numbers. Each of this binary numbers then represents one row of the matrix.

Since the only number to define the martix is `n` (in the example `n = 3`) we can use that to calculate the dimensions of the matrix:

- rows: `2 ^ n` (in the example `2^3 = 8`)
- columns: `n`

So we define a matrix of that size `ReDim Matrix(1 To 2 ^ n, 1 To n)`.

Then we need to generatate the decimal numbers from `1` to `7` to be able to convert them into binaries. We do that with a loop: `For i = 0 To 2 ^ n - 1` (in the example this means `For i = 0 To 7`).

In that loop we convert each decimal number `i` into a binary string of the length `n`. We do that using `BinaryString = DecToBin(i, n)`.

Finally we just need to split that string into the columns of our matrix. Therefore we use another loop that loops through the characters of that BinaryString `For c = 1 To n` (which means start with character 1 until character `n`). And fill the matrix:

```
Matrix(i + 1, c) = CLng(Mid$(BinaryString, c, 1))
```

Here `Mid$(BinaryString, c, 1)` picks the character out of the string and `CLng` converts it into a `Long` number so it is numeric and writes it into the correct position of the matrix `Matrix(i + 1, c)`.

Fanally we return that matix as result of our function `CreateMatrix = Matrix`.

Comment: Dear PEH it generated error with n >10 (Error 1004). Anyway What does Mid$ mean?

Comment: @MinhDuc See my edit. I replaced the `WorksheetFunction.Dec2Bin` which is limited to decimals of `511` and replaced it by a custom `DecToBin` which has a limit of `79228162514264337593543950245` for decimals (large numerical values must be entered as string). • `Mid$()` is the [Mid function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/mid-function).

Comment: Excellent PEH, Thank you very much. I wish I can understand all code...

Answer (score 0):

This post is 10 months old. But I saw a new post by the OP which led me here, so I thought I'd share another solution.

This can be solved by formula instead of script.

Suppose in cell A1 of some sheet you place the number for *n*.

In some other cell (say, A3 or C1), you could use the following formula to generate the list in question:

`=FILTER(TEXT(SEQUENCE(10^A1,1,0),REPT("0",A1)),NOT(REGEXMATCH(SEQUENCE(10^A1,1,0)&"","[2-9]")))`

Essentially, this formula creates a `SEQUENCE` of *all* possible numbers between 0 and 10 to the *nth*, formatted to contain *n* digits; then it `FILTER`s out any elements of that sequence that contain any digits from 2 to 9 (i.e., anything *other than* elements containing *only* 1s and 0s).

Comment: Worth to mention that this only works for Excel newer than Office 2019. If you want to do this with formulas then `=DEC2BIN(A1,3)` (where A1 goes from 0 to 7) would be easier to generate the the desired elements. Probably less calculation consuming than generating a lot more and filter.

Comment: I did not realize that the question was specific to Excel. The formula I suggested was for Google Sheets. My error.

Comment: @Eric Well, then no wonder I couldn't run it in Excel ;)